# Resize an ImageButton

Tags: android, xml, android-imagebutton

I know that the question has been asked a lot, but not this case.

How can I make the ImageButton area follows the size of the image source of the ImageButton (the blue rectangle)? I wont't set fixed values for the width and height.

Is that possible?

**1- Normal condition. 2- When I scale the image**
[image: 1- Normal condition. 2- When I scale the image]

**Another description of the problem**
[image: Another description of the problem]

Comment: Just let your ImageView width is wrap_content, so you do not need to scale to anything..

Comment: Thanks nhoxbypass, but why? I want that width fits the Layout, so I can center my image and the Layout itself is setted to wrap_content. Why I can't make it the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need  `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`